# Remove Signature if body contains a string

Tags: vba, string, outlook

The end goal is to remvoe my signature if a certain string is in the body.  So far I can check the body with the following.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    If TypeName(Item) <> "MailItem" Then Exit Sub

       If Item.Body like "*something*" Then
        MsgBox "it's working"
       End If

End Sub
```

All good and off the top of my head I thought I could use

```
 Item.Signature.Remove
```

Only to find out Signature is not a Property.  My sig contains an image also (comp logo).  I've searched and I seem to see that the signature itself is a part of the Body.  Would I need to replace body wih some `TRIM` function plus remove the image?  Not sure where to go or if there's an easier way.

Answer (score 3):

For those who might find this helpful.  The signature is a part of the `Body` Property.  I know that my signature starts with my name so what I did was use the `Instr` function to get that starting postion and go from there.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

If TypeName(Item) <> "MailItem" Then Exit Sub
    If Item.Body Like "*MyCatchPhrase*" Then
      midcount = InStr(Item.Body, "MyFull Name")
      FinNum = midcount - 1
      Item.Body = Left(Item.Body, FinNum)
    End If

End Sub
```